# No exact match was found. Error coming after changing the farm admin account password - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

After changing the farm admin account password (without following the procedure), we are unable to get SP to resolve the domain name users into the secure store and other applications, all this is happening into the CA. Any help much appreciated.

Other errors on the log:

> Error updating the account password for process identity Id
>   1ba43229-ca04-4ad9-a8e9-6eecd63f53a6, please fix manually. The type
>   initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.SessionStateScope' threw
>   an exception.
>
> Cannot alter the role 'SPDataAccess', because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permission.
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_putObjectTVP',
>   database

Comment: same farm admin account is being used for these services?

Comment: Yes same just different password

Comment: can you try to enter the exiting password one more time (Central admin > security > manage accounts > edit the account and check use exiting account and hit ok)

Comment: I followed this instructions to update the password but no result, same problem http://www.tsls.co.uk/index.php/2011/01/21/how-to-change-the-farm-service-account-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Hi Waqas, I did that already no result, thanks for the help

Comment: on the same page (where you enter password), at the bottom it list on which services this password is being used, could you please share the screen shot

Comment: Farm Account
Distributed Cache
Claims to Windows Token Service
User Profile Synchronization Service
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service
Security Token Service Application
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application
Work Management Service Application
PowerPivot Service Application

Comment: I couldn't upload a screen shot, but I sent you the list

Comment: did you update the password for the UPA sync service? on which server you are seeing the error ( all or one)

Comment: Yes, I did. The error is on the Sharepoint server

Comment: in IIS on the failing server which app pool stoped?

Comment: SharePoint web services root is stoped

Comment: How many servers you have?

Comment: 1 SP, 1 Data base. 1 webapp

Comment: one more thing that I notice is on the previous existing secure services all users there are starting with i:0#.w<domainname\username> instead of the regular domain name\user...also this user from AD not showing issue is only happening into the CA on the SP server, if I log into a client with the appropriated credentials I can see all AD users and give permissions.

Comment: looks like issue with UPA, can you stop and start the upa? other than name issue, are you seeing different issue when browsing site collection

Comment: I stop and start UPA all seems normal, no any other error, in the site collections the performance point service is not working because into the secure store, usernames are not correct.

Comment: can you reset IIS on the server, check if SS app pool come online. when you click on the SS service what error you see? how many users you have in the ss?

Comment: No errors are coming after IIS reset, the app pool comes online.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Reference links,

[Step by Step: Changing the SharePoint 2013 Farm Account Password](http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2015/06/step-by-step-changing-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Changing SharePoint 2013 farm passwords](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mbakirov/2016/07/29/changing-sharepoint-farm-passwords/)

[SharePoint 2010 – Service Accounts Passwords Change Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charliechirapuntu/2013/01/16/sharepoint-2010-service-accounts-passwords-change-guide/)

Try this one too

For the farm account, do the following

- change the password farm admin account in active directory
- now go to central admin> security> configure managed account...on this page 
  click edit on the farm account
- now select the option "use existing password" and enter the new password 
  which you did on step 1
- wait for couple of min and then test
- in some cases you may have to reset IIS

This will cause brief outage for whole SharePoint farm.

For site collection

SharePoint don't store the password of site collection level user i.e. Site collection admin etc. You can change password it anytime and will not cause the issue.

change the password At active directory
Now login to site collection with new password

Comment: Thanks, Navi9, I already tried all the recommendations you wrote but no luck, still the same

Comment: one more thing that I notice is on the previous existing secure services all users there are starting with i0#:domainname\username instead of the regular domain name\user...also this user from AD not showing issue is only happening into the CA on the SP server, if I log into a client with the appropriated credentials I can see all AD users and give permissions.

Comment: I mean i:0#.w<domanin\user> so when I tried to save the no exact match was found error is comng